# add more reducers after store had been created

Tags: javascript, redux

is it possible to add reducers after the store has been created?

example :
let's say I have this react app

```
//App.jsx
const reducers = {foo : []}
const store = createStore(combineReducers(reducers));

const App = () => <Provider store={store}><Test/></Provider>
```

---

```
//Test.jsx
class Test extends Component {

     componentDidMount() {
          //here I want to add new reducer to the store
          //I will handle duplication problem
          //I'm looking for something like this
          store.appendReducer('REDUCER_KEY' , someReducer);  
     }
     ...
}
export default connect()(Test)
```

I'm wondering if this possible, if so how to implement this.

> I have an idea in mind, but it's not perfect. I can add a global callback function and listen for any call at the root component, then recreate the store when any call happens. the problem with this it will cause the whole component tree to be rerendered at any reducer addition.

Comment: I have to ask: why would you do this? The store is usually tightly linked to the code during development. Any dynamically added reducer would not be available during coding.

Comment: @pintxo I'm trying to build a small library, and I thought that I may need to add new reducers after the store had been created. I didn't write any code yet, just thinking of ways to implement the library.so I wondered if this possible.

Answer (score 2):

yes it's possible some thing like that

```
const newRootReducer = combineReducers({
  existingSlice: existingSliceReducer,
  newSlice: newSliceReducer
})

store.replaceReducer(newRootReducer)
```

you can check the DOC  for more info [redux DOC](https://redux.js.org/recipes/code-splitting)